# How to minify multiple javascript file in phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I want to minify and combined all my javascript files in phalcon using the asset manager. Below is the code i have.

```
  $this->assets
                ->collection('footer')
                ->addJs('js/jquery/jquery.validationEngine-en.js')
                ->addJs('js/jquery/jquery.validationEngine.js')
                ->addJs('js/external/googlemap.js')
                ->addJs('js/external/highcharts.js')
                ->addJs('js/external/highcharts-exporting.js')
                ->addJs('js/gmaps.js')
                ->addJs('js/detailed.js')
                ->join(true)
                ->setTargetPath('final.js')
                ->setTargetUri('production/final.js')
                ->addFilter(new Phalcon\Assets\Filters\Jsmin());
```

When i try to view source and view final.js file, i get an error

> The collection does not exist in the manager

Does anyone know why the above error happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. I am hitting the error message because i did not specify the correct collection name in the views.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to call like this in view file

```
$this->assets->outputJs('footer');
```